# SQL Server date conversion is 68 years behind the actual date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I want to convert an `integer` to a `date` format. I am using the following script:

```
SELECT CAST(7549 as datetime)
```

It returns me a date `1920-09-02`

However, `7549` actual date is `1988-08-31`

Can anyone please help me how to perform correct mapping?

Comment: The best approach will depend on your DBMS; please update your question's tags to indicate whether this is PostgreSQL, Oracle, MySQL, SQLServer, . . .

Comment: From WHERE you found that 7549 actual date is 1988-08-31 ?!?

Comment: 7549 is actually 1920-09-02. How could you say that 7549 is actually 1988-08-31?

Comment: I am reverse engineering a database. I am trying to match the actual values with the values in the database.

Comment: My DBMS is SQL SERVER

Comment: What about `SELECT DATEADD(d, 24835, CAST(7549 AS datetime))` ?

Comment: Thanks, shA.t. This is what I wanted. But could you please elaborate your solution and also the magic number 24835. Please post it as an answer to my question. So that other also get benefit out of it.

Comment: 0 IN SQL Server is 1900-01-01. As opposed to whatever SQL version you may have previously used, where it seems to be 1967-12-31. Try `DATEADD(DAY, 7549, '1967-12-31')` or substitute any INT there. EDIT: FYI Casting an INT to a datetime adds that number of days to 0, which is 1900-01-01 in SQL Server

Comment: 7549 is just an integer. What kind of "date" does that represent? And what is the logic that should convert that to 1988-08-31?

Answer (score 1):

See the reverse

```
DECLARE @YourDate AS Datetime

SET @YourDate = '1920-09-02'
SELECT CAST(@YourDate AS INT) --7549

SET @YourDate = '1988-08-31'
SELECT CAST(@YourDate AS INT) -- 32384
```

Comment: Unfortunately. its not the correct solution for me. I am not sure if CAST is the right function to use for my task

Comment: I didn't give you a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result as '`1988-08-31 00:00:00.000`', try with the following scripts.

```
SELECT CAST(7549 as datetime)-CAST('1832-01-03' as datetime)
```

OR

```
SELECT CAST(7549 as datetime)+CAST(24835 as datetime)
```